# cakephp how make to ignore directory?

Tags: cakephp, routes, directory

How make to ignore directory xxx in root?

- app
- xxx
- lib

In my router files I have:

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'view', 'home'));
Router::connect('/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'view'));
```

Comment: Please specify 1) what you mean by "ignore", and 2) what have you tried?  Those routes don't look like anything related to "xxx".

Comment: Ignore = exclude the directory xxx by the rules of routing. I have tried to insert htaccess RewriteRule ^(xxx).* - [NC,L]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### move the folder under webroot

This question/problem has nothing to do with routes.

It seems highly likely that ignore means "the contents of xxx are inaccessible". This is caused by the `.htaccess` file [in the top level directory](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/.htaccess):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
  RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Which (very deliberately) prevents accessing anything *except* the webroot.

However, it's very easy to account for this behavior, simply move the xxx folder from this:

```
-app
-xxx
-lib
```

To:

```
-app
    -webroot
        -xxx
-lib
```

And then, since the url `example.com/xxx/file.ext` maps to the path `.../app/webroot/xxx/file.ext`, the contents of the folder are accessible.